# FibreChannel topology

Tags: brocade, topology, san, fibrechannel

I trying to understand SAN topology. 
If we have fabric and fabric mode with auto data rate is set == means we will get F_ports, right? 
And if we need use 8G link from SAN storage and no fibre mode is availible, does it OK to use p2p. And is so, it would be N_port. 
By brocade http://www.brocade.com/content/html/en/deployment-guide/brocade-vcs-storage-dp/GUID-48CF1FD9-DB97-494F-84C2-545F5027BD67.html 
i know that F_port using to connect N_port. 
Does *any* SAN switch using that logic? 
I cannot make changes to the switch, but can change node connection setting. 
And there is availible only FC-AL and P2P without auto datarate.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

N-port is a node port, actually it's HBA on a server or a port on a storage array. It is used to connect a node to a Fibre Channel switch. On Brocade switch you would usually have F-port, which is "Fabric port" used to connect with node port. In rare situations you can get L- or FL- port on the switch when you have to deal with mostly deprecated FC-Loop topology. So do not specify FC-AL on your storage.

In your case set P2P on the storage and you will likely get normal F-port on the switch.

Answer (score 1):

Point-2-point mode is the opposite of arbitrated-loop mode (AL). You usually do not want AL if there's a switch. Set all ports to P2P at all times unless you really do need AL mode (when you chain multiple devices on a single port).

In AL mode, ports pass on traffic to other ports behind them in the loop. At any time, there can only two ports active in a loop.